# Webrtc startup resolution

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I have webrtc application and works perfectly with max resolution as 1280 X 720. However webrtc would take some time (around 20 seconds from start of call) to ramp up to 1280 X 720. Would start from 640 X 480 and then some intermediate resolution and then to 1280 X 720. Is there any way better to force webrtc to start with intended resolution?

I tried setting x-google-min-bitrate and x-google-start-bitrate but didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - setting video codec to VP9 (default is VP8) allowed to get configured resolution at start of video call.